# Does contributing to Close/Reopen votes outside of the review queue contribute to your total?

Tags: support, badges, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

At 250 and 1000 reviews in a category, you get a badge. But if you either vote to close or reopen outside of the queue, does it still count towards this total? And if not (as I suspect at the moment), why not?

Comment: I made the 'vote-to-reopen' tag since it seemed applicable and the 'vote-to-close' tag already existed.

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't.

The only queue that you get credit for from participating outside of the queue is the Edit Queue.

As far as the why, my guess is that it simply comes down to the fact that the queue is a specialized tool added much later than the features it tracks, so those features haven't been tied back to their respective queues.