# Review actions performed outside of the Review Queue should contribute towards earning badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, review

Based on this screenshot of the review queue history:

[image: screenshot of review queue history]

It doesn't appear that review efforts performed outside of the queue contribute towards a player earning the applicable badge. I know that I had cast a VtC on the 'Player shows up inconsistently' question which I accessed by clicking on it from the front page. This action occurred before casting a Leave Open vote via the queue on a subsequent question.

I personally tend to not like reviewing through the queue since it feels unnatural for me. Rather, I go through the front page, read through the questions, and then respond accordingly (i.e. comment, comment with VtC, provide an answer). A lot of times, I'll read a question and then start clicking on linked questions or hop over to similar questions as well and sometimes I'll perform review actions there as well (especially if it's recent). In addition, there are plenty of times where I'll read a question from the queue and before issuing a vote I'll want to get a better look at what's already been done/said as it relates to comments so I'll click the question (which takes me out of the review queue) so I can see everything and perform my review action from there.

A [similar question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3367/31402) was asked about this some 6 years ago, but only 1 answer was provided and seemed uncertain.

Normally, I wouldn't give worry too much about this, however, when moderator elections occur a major component of how we rate and rank potential candidates is dependent upon certain review badges that they've earned. The system in place now favors those that complete review actions through the review queue and disadvantages those who may prefer to perform those actions in a different manner.

Is it feasible for the badge progress tracker to track review actions performed by users outside of the review queue? Is there a particular reason why we would prefer the badge tracker to only count actions done through the queue?

Comment: So is the problem that things like review queue badges aren't exactly accurate in a meaningful way and yet they are used in calculating the score displayed during moderator elections? I wonder how much people even pay attention to the score though there's certainly no way of figuring that out, hmmm

Comment: Related/Identical MSE post: "[Include reviews made outside of /review in progress towards the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111482)"

Comment: In fact, I'll recommend that readers (incl. OP) interact over there ^^, since there's nothing RPGSE's going to be able to do on this matter. Unless there's a thought that our use-patterns present a particular harm/omission where review badges are concerned.

Comment: @Medix2 I often pay attention to the score, part of my mentality when doing so is if you're averse to doing reviews then moderator's probably not for you. Not to be dismissive of comprehensive responses, but I am often limited in my available time. So when we have elections, I will often screen out candidates' whose score is notably low and I suspect others may as well. I then pretty much just read the responses by the remainder.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Genuine thanks, that actually made a lot of sense!